# Is there any danger in chopping down every tree I see?

Tags: stardew-valley

I recently cleared my farm of all trees and rocks and personally kept the seeds. But if I just so happened to chop down every non-fruit bearing tree in the whole town and also sold/destroyed all of their seeds does that have any negative effects on the game? And if in the future I wish to plant some more, will I be able to get maple seeds, pinecones, acorns from another source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no danger, no. Trees outside your farm will regrow over time. (I haven't timed it, but my offhand impression is it takes about half a season or a bit more.)

This makes town and forest trees a renewable source of wood, sap, and tree seeds. Seeds being a renewable resource means you can always reforest your farm if desired.

Comment: Good to know. Now I don't feel so bad getting them all out of my way haha.

Comment: Also it seems that trees on the outskirts of your farm will sometimes drop seeds which will automatically grow into saplings. And your farm gets pretty green after winter too :)

Comment: Seeds can also occasionally be found by rummaging through trash cans.